# Vagrant won't recognize VirtualBox on x64-Windows7 (already running JRuby)

Tags: windows, 64-bit, installation, virtualbox, jrubyonrails

I'm trying to get Vagrant up and running on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine, and I'm continually getting an error that "Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox!" Here's what I've got installed:

- JRE 6.0.230.25 x64
- JRuby 1.6.0.0
- Ruby 1.8.7.330 (Windows)
- VirtualBox 3.2.12
- Current version of Vagrant (as of 01/18/11)

I've been getting the same error every single time I try a command such as

```
vagrant box add eyu package.box
```

and now I'm kind of at my wits' end. Any suggestions?

(And I only installed the Windows version of Ruby after I had been wrestling with this for a while. I don't know if it could potentially causing some other conflict to have JRuby and Ruby installed on the same machine, but I've been getting this error before and after I installed it.)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Have you put the Virtualbox commands in your path?

`set path=%path%;c:/programfiles/oracle/bin` or similar?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that -- I ended up giving up on the whole effort, for other reasons. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this problem was caused by the Java Home variable still pointing to the Java 32-bit version (Program Files(x86)).

Also: when you change the Java Home variable, restart your cmd for it to take effect ;-) (drove me nuts before I figured that one out)

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem, in the end the solution was to make sure JRuby was using a 64b JRE to execute: see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/jnksKOR_Qhs.

Note that if you have JAVA_HOME set in your environment, even if you install JRuby with the installer that includes the JRE, it will use the JRE from your JAVA_HOME. You have to manually set JAVA_HOME=c:\jruby-x.y.z\jre.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that vagrant is looking for "VBoxManage" instead of "VBoxManage.exe".

I changed the file:

```
<VAGRANT>/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb
```

at line 26:

```
- @vboxmanage_path = "VBoxManage"
+ @vboxmanage_path = "VBoxManage.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks, @Kaniabi! It turns out, that Vagrant is very specific about the Env variable format.

It seeks the presence of a `"VBOX_INSTALL_PATH"` variable with the value that ends with `"\"`. What a logic! Anyhow, I adjusted the value and the "VBoxManage error" has gone.

(Ref. ```HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.6.2\plugins\providers\virtualbox\driver\base.rb, line 28```, and on..)

Answer (score 0):

Similar with **Kaniabi** I changed the path to the absolute one:

```
- @vboxmanage_path = "VBoxManage"
+ @vboxmanage_path = "c:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe"
```

Cheers!